# Feature Class Unique Fields For ESRI Collector Survey

Tags: feature-class, arcgis-collector, unique-value

I have a suite of empty feature classes I use for ESRI Collector surveying. They are in a FGD. I want the PhotoID field in my Photos feature class to contain unique records, so fieldworkers don't keep accidentally re-using numbers. I am having a lot of trouble establishing this. 
Any suggestions how to best do this?

Comment: Create attachments and forget about unique photo name.